# nested if condition and break

Tags: python, if-statement

All,

I have a code that looks like this:

```
if condition

  if condition: 
     do something
  elif condition:
     do something
  else:
     break
else: 
  do something
```

I have a nested `if condition` and I introduced a break in the inner "`if condition`" with the intention to break from that inner `if condition` if conditions are not met and move on to the "`else`" of the outer `if condition`.

In your opinion, does it make sense to do that way? is there a simple way of writing the problem.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your code?

Comment: Where is the loop you are talking about?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the inner checks can be hoisted up into the outer check, but we'll need a representative code sample to determine that

Comment: @serbia99   sorry i corrected the error

Comment: the code is a bit long. was tying to summarize the coding issue i am facing

Comment: You don't need to break from the `if` condition, may it be the inner or the outer. When you end up in the outer `if`condition, you will not move to the outer `else` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to just repeat your first condition. Then there is no nesting and the `else` of the inner `if` is the same as the `else` of the outer `if`.

```
if conditionA and conditionB:
    do X
elif conditionA and conditionC:
    do Y
else: 
    do Z
```

If `conditionA` is costly, then store the result in some temporary variable.

Another option, you could move your inner `if` to a function (including any computations and preparations to be performed in between `conditionA` and `conditionB`) and have it `return False` in the `else` case, then check both `conditionA` and the result of that function in the outer `if`. However, IMHO this variant might be much harder to understand.

```
def inner():
    preparation stuff
    if conditionB: 
        do X
    elif conditionC:
        do Y
    else:
        return False
    return True

if not (conditionA and inner()):
    do Z
```

Or, of course, you could just repeat the `do Z` part, or put it in a function and call that function in two places:

```
if conditionA:
    preparation stuff
    if conditionB: 
        do X
    elif conditionC:
        do Y
    else:
        do Z # should be a function call
else: 
    do Z # same here
```

Comment: that is a good idea. the only issue is that condition B  is dependent on a variable that I need to define after condition A is met . But i see what you mean i could explore that option too

Comment: @SBad. That's why you need to post sample code in your question.

Comment: @SBad See my update; it's a bit longer, but it's in fact rather close to your `if/break`.

Comment: @tobias_k  honestly your first suggestion will do the job ..i am testing it as i am writing this message

Answer (score 1):

The `break` command is for *loops* only, not for `if-elif-else` construction.

I. e. you may break only from `for` or `while` loops.

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> ```
> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Break is used to jump or exit from a loop not an if condition.

You can just do

```
if condition
  {

  if condition: 

     do something

  elseif condition:

     do something
}
else:{

   do something
}
```

Comment: Not in Python you can't

Comment: actually cant you do it with proper indendation

Comment: Colons are still mandatory and there's no such thing as elseif

Comment: Also, this doesn't address OP's question, which is how to get into the outer else.